# TexWorks give error message \AddToHook{begindocument/before}

Tags: errors, templates

I am trying to compile the thesis template given here.[Link to thesis template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) The file opens without a hitch when I run it for the first time but as soon as I make a change as small as changing my name in the code section. It throws this error.

```
translations.sty
73
Undefined control sequence.
l.73 \AddToHook
               {begindocument/before}{
```

Comment: `\AddToHook` is a fairly recent addition to the LaTeX kernel it was added in the October 2020 release of LaTeX (LaTeX 2020-10-01). If your system is older than that, it will probably not know `\AddToHook`. If possible update your TeX system (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864). If you are stuck with an older version of TeX live that can no longer be updated or with a version of TeX live that is shipped by your operating system, you may have to install a new TeX live.

Comment: as Moewe says \AddToHook is fairly recent, but if you do not want to upgrade your latex, the link you give to the "template" links to a version on Overleaf which is dated 2017 so years before \AddToHook was added, that version will work with an older latex so you could copy it to your local system

Comment: you seem to have a quite new version of translations.sty which already use the new hooks.

Comment: @all Where can I find user-guide (or something like that) for the recent command `\AddToHook`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the above error update your version of Tex.