# Changes package - use different color for added, replaced and deleted text

Tags: color, changes, customize

I am planning to use [changes](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/changes/changes.english.withcode.pdf) package for marking up changes in the latex document. I like to denote new additions in green, modifications in blue and deletions in red. However, changes package uses the same color for every change. Is it possible to use different colors for the above three commands?

Currently, since I am the only author editing the tex file, I've defined three authors as below

```
\definechangesauthor[name=new additions, color=teal]{new}
\definechangesauthor[name=in place modifications, color=blue]{modified
\definechangesauthor[name=deletions, color=red]{deleted}
```

and when adding, modifying, or deleting text, I use corresponding `id`. However, this cannot be used when there are multiple authors. Further, there are redundancies here. I have to use the command `\added` and still specify `id=new`. And in the rendered pdf document, along with the green color, there will be a superscipt saying it is `new`. How can I do this more efficiently and cleanly?

Edit 1:
I have been able to get rid of the superscript by setting `\usepackage[authormarkup=none]{changes}` as suggested in the first comment to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/694064/178369). However, it still requires me to use `\added[id=new]{new text}`

Comment: The possibility to use different colors for added, deleted and replaced is not provided for the package `changes` according to the documentation. Possibly, because the colors are already used to differentiate different authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuisance with writing `\added[id=new]{new text}` can be avoided
by defining

```
\newcommand\noidadded{\added[id=new]}
```

and then wring simply `\noidadded{new text}`.

---

@Ulrike Fischer's approach is very interesting, but has two drawbacks:
First, it requires a recent version of latex kernel. The second is that  using his hooked `\added`
has effect also for all following commands of the package (unless they are also hooked, to get their own colour). The following reduces the impact (but has some side-effects, too).

```
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/added/before}{\bgroup\def\Changes@AuthorColor{red}}
\AddToHook{cmd/added/after}{\egroup}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you. May be @Ulrike Fischer's answer is better than this, but I don't know. I am accepting this mainly because I understand this easily, requires minimal changes to my existing solution, I ca be confident that this does not affect anything else and that this supports older Latex version also.

Answer (score 3):

For one author you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/added/before}{\def\Changes@AuthorColor{red}}
\AddToHook{cmd/deleted/before}{\def\Changes@AuthorColor{green}}
\AddToHook{cmd/replaced/before}{\def\Changes@AuthorColor{blue}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
{\added{added} \deleted{deleted} \replaced{new}{old}}

\added{added} \deleted{deleted} \replaced{new}{old}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more authors you will have to be more specific about what should happen. And you should also provide an example that can be used for a test.

Comment: Can you please explain to me how this works? Especially, how the `AddToHook` helps.

Comment: `\AddToHook` is a fairly recent addition to the LaTeX kernel. It was added in the October 2020 release of LaTeX (LaTeX 2020-10-01). (source: moewe at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602066 ). So it is latex kernel thing, and it will not work in older versions of tex. Working can be understood from page 28-29 of https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/base/lthooks-doc.pdf .

Comment: It seems that under simple circumstances, the first of them is equivalent to changing the definition `\added`  to `<HOOKTEXT><OLD\added>`.  You could simply define `\newcommand\myadd{\def\Changes@AuthorColor{green}\added}`  and use `\myadd` with the same effect. 
Note that  (with \AddToHook or without it) the change of `\Changes@AuthorColor` has effect to **all** following commands of the package (unless us localize by `{ ... }`).

Comment: @minorChaos did you try your \myadd?

Comment: your changed your command after I made the remark, now it should work. But the main point of using a hook is to avoid to have define lots of new commands.

Comment: `\AddToHook` works well in the preamble. But it does not work after `\begin{document}`.  Just a warning, this is no trouble for me.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: I did not mean to suggest the `\newcommand` approach, I just tried to explain the behaviour - the global impact of hooked `\added`  was a surprise to me.

Comment: Corrections: My `\myadd` requires `\makeatletter` before `\newcommand`. And it does not win over the Hooks if both are used simultaneously.