# Suppress author tag when using changes package

Tags: changes, customize

When using the [changes](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/changes/changes.english.withcode.pdf) package, it highlights the changed text and adds a superscript denoting the author id. Is it possible to suppress this superscript? I use different colors for different authors.

PS: This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/694063/178369), but is also a stand-alone question.

Comment: You've not given a minimal working example for me to start from, but does `\usepackage[authormarkup=none]{changes}` do what you want?

Comment: This works, thanks! If you can add it as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Teepeemm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/107497/teepeemm) said,

```
\usepackage[authormarkup=none]{changes}
```

should work.